# Vue-cli: arrow key not working while creating new project on git bash windows

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to create a project which Vue-cli through Git bash Window.

Git version 2.14.1.windows.1

Vue version 3.0.0-rc.3

For some reason the cursor is still visible during installation.

[image]

And when I press any arrow key, the option does not change, only the cursor move around. (However, pressing enter still process me to the next step).

Searching for a solution with google does not let me anywhere, only a few Github bug report: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/283

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. The solution I came up with was:

```
$ winpty vue.cmd create `<project-name>`
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Git Bash does not seem to be an interactive terminal.

Answer (score 10):

Surprisingly, **Windows Command Prompt** is not suffered from this bug. So my solution is:

> Hold Shift + Right click project folder -> choose **Open command window here**

This does not solve the root cause. If you happen to know a better option, please post your answer.

**Note:**
If you get error cannot execute scripts on powershell, then you need to enable script execution. Run powershell as administrator and run the following command to enable scripts on it:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 10):

## UPDATED 2021, Apr 4th!

Here's a **`CTRL+C and CTRL+V`** step-by-step practical solution to solve this. The fact that you have this trouble means you are on **Windows** and you most likely use **Git Bash**.

1. **Using Git Bash** a quick solution would be typing
   `echo 'alias vue="winpty vue.cmd"' >> ~/.bashrc`
   This will not overwrite `.bashrc`, and instead append the text on the left of `>>`
2. Restart your bash. That means close it and open it again.

If you're looking for "Why do I have to add such thing to `.bashrc`?", I think another user has mentioned that. If you found this helpful please upvote it so others can see it too.

#### Old answer

You can try to make a file `.bashrc` in your current `<UserNameProfile>`.
Then, inside of it use your favourite text editor and write

```
alias vue='winpty vue.cmd'
```

Then restart your bash. And you should be able to use `vue` as it should be on the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to solve this issue which is explained in the **[Vue CLI Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)**:

1 - You must run the command as **`winpty vue.cmd create hello-world`**.

2 - If you still want to use the **`vue create hello-world`** syntax. You'll need to add the following line, **`alias vue='winpty vue.cmd'`**, to your **`~/.bashrc`** file. Then, you'll need to restart your Git Bash terminal session to pull in the updated **`bashrc`** file.

Answer (score 2):

Git Bash is not an interactive shell. That's why you should use something that is by default interactive such as CMD or you have to do as mentioned in the [Vue CLI doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create):

> If you are on Windows using Git Bash with minTTY, the interactive
>   prompts will not work. You must launch the command as winpty vue.cmd
>   create hello-world. If you however want to still use the vue create
>   hello-world syntax, you can alias the command by adding the following
>   line to your ~/.bashrc file. alias vue='winpty vue.cmd' You will need
>   to restart your Git Bash terminal session to pull in the updated
>   bashrc file.
>   Vue CLI is an interactive CLI. But Git Bash is not an interactive shell. That's why it won't work. [Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2117)